# Fastest way to create object in Java

Tags: java

There are several methods to create Instance in Java 
(Different ways are new operator, cloning, reflection and DE-serialization etc)

So among them which is the fastest of all ?

Comment: Fastest typing: `new YourObject();` :)

Answer (score 1):

In such a case fastest means which one of those executes less operations before actually allocating the memory for the object. It is easy to determine that `new` is the fastest among those because it doesn't bear the overhead created from the others such as clone etc.

Comment: What kind of overhead is there in `clone`? Nothing is easy to determine without measuring, and even *with* measuring it's difficult.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Usually I use clone() to actually return an object that has some properties set as the original object and not only return an empty object. As you said things are depending on the situation.

Comment: Well, that's comparing apples and oranges, then. Pure instantiation can only be compared with pure cloning, with no custom logic added. BTW I just did measure: `new Object()` takes 5.5 ns for me and `o.clone()` takes 9.5 ns. Either is hardly to ever show up as the bottleneck, making the question rather moot at the outset.

Comment: @Marko We are trying to create like 50000 objects of same Class. So i wanted to know the which method takes less time.

Comment: Take the worst case: 10 ns * 50,000 = half a millisecond. Does that worry you?